# Passing props from Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

How to call props from redux without passing props from the parent component.

```
...
<Component name={name}/>
...
```

I want use `props.something()` here

```
const Component = (name) => {


//how to call props here? 
//ex : props.something()

}

export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(Component)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [props are passed as functional component's arguments](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#function-and-class-components):

```
const Component = (props) => {
// props.name
}
```

Or you can use [Destructuring syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment):

```
const Component = ({name}) => {
// name
}
```

Comment: Can i use name and props.something() together?

Comment: of course, try reading the docs beforehand https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html

Answer (score 0):

Also you can destructure more than one items from props.

```
<MyComponent name={name} title={title} description={description} />
```

```
const MyComponent = ({ name, title, description )} => {
  // ...
}

export default MyComponent;
```